# Quantum entanglement correlations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I have a vague idea of what entanglement is but I am stuck at one place: we all know that entanglement is destroyed with time. this is called decoherence. I wish to know if there is any correlation between the time taken for decoherence and the mass of the particle involved? Links to paper advocating the same result will be appreciated.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. What is the "strength" of entanglement? Or it's "duration"?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please note that we hold questions to high standards of quality. Punctuation, spelling, capitalization, and format are important parts of making a question easy to understand. English sentences should all begin with a capital letter. The word "I" is always capitalized. Do not use more than one question mark per sentence.

Comment: The only conceivable answer I can think of for this question is to discuss how mass affects decoherence, but since OP has not defined what is meant by "strength of entanglement" and has not indicated why entanglement should have a finite life time, it's hard to know where to start.

Comment: @DanielSank Yes, danielsank, I want to know how mass affects the decoherence.

Comment: No, we don't all know that entanglement is destroyed with time. If I take an entangled state and isolate it such that nothing interacts with it, the entanglement will never be destroyed.

Comment: Hypothetically it is true. "Isolating" is a word that does not exist in real life.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to provide a citation for something that doesn't happen, and no one thinks happens. And a mass dependence or distance dependence is exactly such a thing.

Entanglement happens. However, entanglement is a consequence of linearity. And it's how measurements happen so it is very common. Entanglement is easily created and simply has no bearing on distance or mass.

Sure, mass matters in that it takes takes time for a more massive thing to change with the same push so it could take longer to create an entanglement if it takes longer to do everything.

**Edit below**

> I have a vague idea of what entanglement is

Don't settle for vague. When a multiparticle state can't be written as the product of single particle states it is entangled. Simple as that, and absolutely no room for vagueness.

> but I am stuck at one place:

No, you aren't stuck. The definition is as above and it isn't vague and you aren't stuck. You want to know about decoherence and mass which is a different issue and you can tell people you arconfused about entanglement or even tell yourself and it is the storytelling that is the barrier because you do understand it.

Here is another example for differential forms. A two form is called simple if it is the exterior product of two one forms.  For instance $$(a_0dw+a_1dx+a_2dy+a_3dz)\wedge(b_0dw+b_1dx+b_2dy+b_3dz)$$ is simple and $\alpha dw\wedge dx+\beta dy\wedge dz$ is not simple. How do we know $\alpha w\wedge dx+\beta dy\wedge dz$ isn't simple? If it were then by antisymmetry its wedge with itself would be zero but its wedge with itself is $$(\alpha dw\wedge dx+\beta dy\wedge dz)\wedge (\alpha dw\wedge dx+\beta dy\wedge dz)$$ equals $2\alpha\beta w\wedge dx\wedge dy\wedge dz\neq 0.$ (You could also verify that no a and b work.)

So it isn't anything more than some algebra, entangled just means not factorizable.

> we all know that entanglement is destroyed with time.

This simply isn't true. Measurement is a process by which the device and the object have their states become entangled, and the entanglement persists forever.

> this is called decoherence.

Decoherence is about figuring out situations where the multiple results of the object that became entangled with the different states of the device device are sufficiently incapable of becoming unentangled by an effectively thermodynamically accessible path. Its the exact opposite, its telling you when an entanglement is not going away. Sure, each of the now separate parts of the entanglement has an internal perspective where their is not entanglement. But that's a perspective. The point of decoherence is that that perspective isn't distinguishable from what the actual dynamics predicts.

> I wish to know if there is any correlation between the time taken for decoherence and the mass of the particle involved?

There isn't a precise time for decoherence to occur any more than there is a size where thermodynamics starts to hold. And in fact, there always remains a very small chance that you can tell it didn't happen, its a perspective and you you design it so that it is very very very unlikely to hurt you even if it is technically not something tiu can know happens.